# Python - Transpose data in desired format

Tags: python, excel, transpose

Python newbie here. May I please know how can I transpose below given data into desired format mentioned below?

Source data:

[Source Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icDag.png)

Output data must look like:

[Output data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FLME.png)

Please advise.

My Code so far:

```
# Transposing an excel file using python
import pandas as pd

# Location of the file
loc = ("C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\Python_Files\\data.xlsx")

# Reading the file
df=pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\Python_Files\\data.xlsx")

# Transposing the file
df.T.to_excel('C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\Python_Files\\data1.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code as formatted text in your question.

Comment: You are still able to actually create the (example) input and output list structures even if you're not yet sure of how to programmatically get from one to another. It only needs to be representative. This helps us test and gives assurance that we give you the anticipated output. Image links can expire and your question would be rendered nonsensical

Comment: I added my code above as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. Just for anyone's reference, code below:

```
import pandas as pd

# Location of the file
loc = "C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\Python_Files\\data.xlsx"

# Reading the file
df=pd.read_excel(loc)

#Transposing the file
out = df.pivot_table(values='H', index=['V','ED','D','F','SF','T'],columns=['SPH'], fill_value=0)
print(out)

out1 = pd.DataFrame(out).reset_index()
print(out1)

out2 = pd.DataFrame(out1.transpose()).reset_index()
print(out2)

out2.rename(columns={'SPH':-1}, inplace=True)
print(out2)

out2.rename(columns=lambda x: x+1, inplace=True)
print(out2)

out2.rename(columns={0:'Name'}, inplace=True)
print(out2)

#Save
out2.to_excel("C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\Python_Files\\data1.xlsx", index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try importing the original data as a dataframe using `pandas` library with the function `pandas.read_csv` [read_csv documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and then transposing the dataframe using  the function `pandas.DataFrame.transpose` [transpose documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html)

Comment: Thank you! I just entered my code above. But I am not sure how to change the code to exactly replicate the output file.